# MCMCglmm: extract posterior se of modeled fixed effects

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc, standard-error

I need to extract the posterior SE estimates my each fixed effect from my model.

For illustrative purposes, a similar dataset to the one I am using would be the `ChickWeight` dataset in base `R`.

The way I extract the posterior estimates and intervals for my fixed effects is like so:

```
#load package
library(lme4)

#model
m.surv<-lmer(weight ~ Time + Diet + (1|Chick), data=ChickWeight)

#load packages
library(MCMCglmm)
library(arm)

#set up for fixed effects
sm.surv<-sim(m.surv)
smfixef.surv=sm.surv@fixef
smfixef.surv=as.mcmc(smfixef.surv)

#which gives
> posterior.mode(smfixef.surv)
(Intercept)        Time       Diet2  ... 
  8.5963329   8.7034260   5.1220436  ...
> HPDinterval(smfixef.surv)
                   lower      upper
(Intercept) -0.90309142 21.3617805
Time         8.42279728  9.0306337
Diet2       -6.84371527 35.1745980
...
attr(,"Probability")
[1] 0.95
>
```

Any suggestions on how I can modify my code to extract the SEs for the fixed effects (`Time` and `Diet2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to extract them from the summary statistics of `smfixef.surv`.

```
s <- summary(smfixef.surv)$statistics
s[grep("Time|Diet", rownames(s)), grep("SE", colnames(s))]
#         Naive SE Time-series SE
# Time  0.02046371     0.02046371
# Diet2 0.96785150     0.96785150
# Diet3 1.02553234     1.02553234
# Diet4 1.07393122     1.66512213
```

Comment: What is the difference between the naive SE and the time-series SE?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist According to `?coda:::summary.mcmc`, the "naive standard error of the mean [ignores] autocorrelation of the chain ... [whereas] time-series standard error [are] based on an estimate of the spectral density at 0".